# Move a turtle to the nearest unoccupied patch in Netlogo

Tags: distance, netlogo

Currently, I have a model with many parameters in it, and one of them is having male yearling deer disperse according to certain criteria. The distance each male yearling disperses is pulled from a log-normal distribution. Here is what I have so far:

```
to move-dispersing-maleyearlings
 ask maleyearlings [
 let chance-disperse random-float 1.001
 if chance-disperse < .62 [  ;;average dispersal rates in Long et. al paper
 let mu 7.5
 let sigma 6.1
 let beta ln (1 + (sigma * sigma) / (mu * mu))
 let S (sqrt beta)
 let M (ln mu) - (beta / 2)
 let new-distance exp (random-normal M S)
 while [any? other turtles-here and dispersal-distance < new-distance]
 [right random 360
   fd 1
    set dispersal-distance dispersal-distance + 1]]]
end
```

So this code should have 62% of the male yearling deer disperse, and they'll disperse a distance of "new-distance". If I am understanding my while loop correctly, they will move until they reach their "new-distance" and until they land on an unoccupied patch.

But now instead what I want to do is have each male yearling deer disperse their respective "new-distance", but if they land on a patch that is occupied, I want them to then move to the nearest unoccupied patch. If the patch they land on after moving "new-distance" is unoccupied, then they would stay on that patch.

Any ideas of how to do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding your request correctly, you want to replace:

```
while [any? other turtles-here and dispersal-distance < new-distance]
 [right random 360
   fd 1
    set dispersal-distance dispersal-distance + 1]]]
```

with code that moves to the closest empty patch. Try something like this (not tested):

```
if any? other turtles-here
[ move-to min-one-of (patches with [not any? turtles-here]) [distance myself]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just so I understand correctly, does this still have each turtle (male yearling deer in my case) move a distance of "new-distance", then if the patch it lands on is occupied, it moves to the closest empty patch? If so, then that's exactly what I need.

Comment: No, I only dealt with the specific question about how to move to the nearest empty patch if they happen to land on a non-empty patch. How the turtle gets to the initial patch is not in this code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it to do what I need it to now!